# Удаление объектов из базы данных Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Всем привет!

Никак не могу корректно удалить данные из ячейки. Ситуация такая: при удалении первой ячейки в консоль выводится принт "Вторая удалена", но удаляется первая. И так далее. Если я пытаюсь удалить данные из последней ячейки (пятой), то приложение падает с ошибкой, но запись все равно удаляется. Ошибка:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason:
>   'Index 4 is out of bounds (must be less than 4)'

Код всего контроллера:

```
class AllTasksTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let realm = try! Realm()

var tasks: Results<Task>!

@IBAction func cancel(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
readTaskAndUpdateUI()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return tasks.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! AllTasksTableViewCell

let bgColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).withAlphaComponent(0.8)
cell.taskName.backgroundColor = bgColor
cell.taskName.layer.cornerRadius = 4
cell.taskName.clipsToBounds = true


cell.taskDate.backgroundColor = bgColor
cell.taskDate.layer.cornerRadius = 4
cell.taskDate.clipsToBounds = true

cell.taskName.text = tasks[indexPath.row].name
cell.taskImage.image = UIImage(data: tasks[indexPath.row].image as Data)
cell.taskDate.text = tasks[indexPath.row].createdAt

return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
let complete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Complete") { (action, indexPath) in
    self.realm.beginWrite()
    self.tasks[indexPath.row].isCompleted = true
    do {
        try! self.realm.commitWrite()
        print("Задача '\(self.tasks[indexPath.row].name) выполнена!'")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in

    self.realm.beginWrite()
    self.realm.delete(self.tasks[indexPath.row])
    do {
        try! self.realm.commitWrite()
        print("Задача '\(self.tasks[indexPath.row].name) удалена!'")
    }
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

complete.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5843137503, green: 0.8235294223, blue: 0.4196078479, alpha: 1)
delete.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9411764741, green: 0.4980392158, blue: 0.3529411852, alpha: 1)
return [complete, delete]
}

func readTaskAndUpdateUI() {
do {
    try realm.write {
        tasks = realm.objects(Task.self).filter("isCompleted = false")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Не удалось загрузить данные. Ошибка - \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Т.е. Вы сначала удаляете элемент из tasks, а затем пытаетесь вывести что-то с ним связанное? Добавьте, к примеру, временную переменную для таких целей.

Comment: @VAndrJ да, все верно! Только что обратил на это внимание. Если удаляю принты в editActionsForRowAt все работает. Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переносим комментарий в ответ. Вот здесь:

```
self.realm.beginWrite()
self.realm.delete(self.tasks[indexPath.row])
do {
    try! self.realm.commitWrite()
    print("Задача '\(self.tasks[indexPath.row].name) удалена!'")
}
```

Вы удаляете элемент из tasks, а затем распечатываете имя "этого" элемента по старому индексу. Если это необходимо, можете использовать временную переменную для хранения имени этого элемента, которое потом и распечатываете.